# Using sendgrid with rails so I can send emails from Google Cloud Platform on port 465. Isnt working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, sendgrid

Its my first time playing around with sending emails in an application. I'm using an instance on the google cloud platform and found out that they [block sending emails form port 465](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#firewalls). They have an work around solution which is using a [third part to send the emails](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#choosing_an_email_service_to_use). I decided to go with sendgrid. But there are a few different options for setting it up and I'm not sure which is the one I'm supposed to use for CGP to allow me to send emails using SSL.

I followed [this tutorial](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html) by sendgrid but I still have the instance blocking port 465. Am I supposed to do it a different way? If so what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by `but I still have the instance blocking port 465`, Sendgrid uses port `587` and the article mentioned that

Comment: @oreoluwa  `465` works testing the app on my local machine `587` gives the error `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol`

Answer (score 1):

To send email via SendGrid from gcp, you need to use port 2525.

See [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid) for more information on using SendGrid.